# How can better Python-GUI be built?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxformbuilder

Very new tho this GUI, trying to build python-GUI.
have designed GUI structure from wx-form builder and using the same.
I have just created two drop-downs and two buttons. 
As you select two drop-down values and click start button,

```
1) It should display what values are selected.
2) `Start` button should be freezed, till some activity completed.
3) `Start` button should be released when some activity is completed or when `Stop` button is clicked.
4) And also, Is it possible to select multiple values from drop-down ?
```

I'm not sure what i've tried is right. Bur will post the code below here, please guide me through this. And also if any good document, please help me.

**test.py**

```
import wx
from wx import xrc


class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        self.res = xrc.XmlResource('test.xrc')
        self.init_frame()
        return True

    def init_frame(self):
        self.frame = self.res.LoadFrame(None, 'mainFrame')
        #text = str(combobox1.currentText())
        self.env = xrc.XRCCTRL(self.frame, 'list1')
        self.service = xrc.XRCCTRL(self.frame, 'list2')
        #self.panel = xrc.XRCCTRL(self.frame, 'panel')
        #self.text1 = xrc.XRCCTRL(self.panel, 'text1')
        #self.text2 = xrc.XRCCTRL(self.panel, 'text2')
        self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSubmit, id=xrc.XRCID('Button1'))
        self.frame.Show()

    def OnSubmit(self,a):
        wx.MessageBox('Your name is %s %s!' %
            (self.env, self.service), 'Feedback')
        #print self.env
        #self.service = xrc.XRCCTRL(self.panel, 'serviceList')
        #self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnNewFrame, self.button)
        self.frame.Show()

        # self.collectLogButton.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.solveFunc )
#       self.stopButton.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clearFunc )

    #def OnNewFrame(self, evt):
    #    self.frame2 = self.res.LoadFrame(None, 'nextFrame')
    #    self.frame2.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

**test.xrc**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<resource xmlns="http://www.wxwindows.org/wxxrc" version="2.3.0.1">
    <object class="wxFrame" name="mainFrame">
        <style>wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL</style>
        <size>500,300</size>
        <title></title>
        <centered>1</centered>
        <object class="wxBoxSizer">
            <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
            <object class="sizeritem">
                <option>0</option>
                <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                <border>5</border>
                <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                    <minsize>-1,80</minsize>
                    <orient>wxHORIZONTAL</orient>
                    <object class="sizeritem">
                        <option>0</option>
                        <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                        <border>5</border>
                        <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                            <minsize>100,-1</minsize>
                            <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxStaticBitmap" name="m_bitmap1">
                                    <bitmap />
                                </object>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                    <object class="sizeritem">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                        <border>5</border>
                        <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                            <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <flag>wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxStaticText" name="titleText">
                                    <font>
                                        <size>30</size>
                                        <family>default</family>
                                        <style>normal</style>
                                        <weight>normal</weight>
                                        <underlined>0</underlined>
                                        <face>Verdana Bold</face>
                                    </font>
                                    <label>TITLE</label>
                                    <wrap>-1</wrap>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                    <object class="sizeritem">
                        <option>0</option>
                        <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                        <border>5</border>
                        <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                            <minsize>100,-1</minsize>
                            <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>1</option>
                                <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                                    <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
                                    <object class="sizeritem">
                                        <option>0</option>
                                        <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                        <border>5</border>
                                        <object class="wxStaticBitmap" name="m_bitmap2">
                                            <bitmap />
                                        </object>
                                    </object>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>1</option>
                                <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                                    <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
                                    <object class="sizeritem">
                                        <option>0</option>
                                        <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                        <border>5</border>
                                        <object class="wxStaticBitmap" name="m_bitmap3">
                                            <bitmap />
                                        </object>
                                    </object>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                </object>
            </object>
            <object class="sizeritem">
                <option>1</option>
                <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                <border>5</border>
                <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                    <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
                    <object class="sizeritem">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <flag>wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL</flag>
                        <border>5</border>
                        <object class="wxFlexGridSizer">
                            <rows>2</rows>
                            <cols>2</cols>
                            <vgap>0</vgap>
                            <hgap>0</hgap>
                            <growablecols></growablecols>
                            <growablerows></growablerows>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxStaticText" name="envLabel">
                                    <font>
                                        <size>20</size>
                                        <family>default</family>
                                        <style>normal</style>
                                        <weight>normal</weight>
                                        <underlined>0</underlined>
                                        <face>Calibri Bold</face>
                                    </font>
                                    <label>List1</label>
                                    <wrap>-1</wrap>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxChoice" name="list1">
                                    <selection>0</selection>
                                    <content>
                                        <item>val1</item>
                                        <item>val2</item>
                                        <item>val3</item>
                                    </content>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxStaticText" name="serviceLabel">
                                    <font>
                                        <size>20</size>
                                        <family>default</family>
                                        <style>normal</style>
                                        <weight>normal</weight>
                                        <underlined>0</underlined>
                                        <face>Calibri Bold</face>
                                    </font>
                                    <label>List2</label>
                                    <wrap>-1</wrap>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxChoice" name="list2">
                                    <selection>0</selection>
                                    <content>
                                        <item>val4</item>
                                        <item>val5</item>
                                        <item>val6</item>
                                    </content>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                    <object class="sizeritem">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <flag>wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL</flag>
                        <border>5</border>
                        <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                            <orient>wxHORIZONTAL</orient>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxButton" name="Button1">
                                    <font>
                                        <family>default</family>
                                        <style>normal</style>
                                        <weight>normal</weight>
                                        <underlined>0</underlined>
                                        <face>Cambria Bold</face>
                                    </font>
                                    <label>Start</label>
                                    <default>0</default>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                            <object class="sizeritem">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                <border>5</border>
                                <object class="wxButton" name="Button2">
                                    <font>
                                        <family>default</family>
                                        <style>normal</style>
                                        <weight>normal</weight>
                                        <underlined>0</underlined>
                                        <face>Calibri Bold</face>
                                    </font>
                                    <label>Stop</label>
                                    <default>0</default>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                </object>
            </object>
        </object>
    </object>
</resource>
```

Comment: @pErs0nZ Thanks for sharing this link. Yes, i have gone through this link already. Using wx-form builder makes easy to design the tool.

Comment: What is the question exactly? @pErs0nZ - The reason there is so much code here is because OP is using a lot of autogenerated code. You can write this much more succinctly yourself without using FormBuilder

Comment: If you need a graphical GUI designer to have a GUI in Python, better use Qt+QtDesigner. Tkinter is good to hack something simple together (would not use it to do more complex stuff). I like wxPython very much if you want to have full control **and** do not want a GUI designer (to my experience wxglade was not helpful and autogenerated a huge amount of code which is difficult to maintain). Read for example @Mike Driscoll s homepage if you want to **learn** how to use wxPython.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll : Place above two files in a directory 'test.py' and 'test.xrc' and run 'python test.py' , GUI will be displayed. And upon clicking submit button, it actually displays some object values (not the actual values selected) , on MAC.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I need to achieve these
1) It should display what values are selected.
2) `Start` button should be freezed, till some activity completed.
3) `Start` button should be released when some activity is completed or when `Stop` button is clicked.
4) And also, Is it possible to select multiple values from drop-down ?

Comment: @nepix32 XRC not supposed to be edited now (XRC generated, once the GUI design finalised). i chose wx-form builder & wxpython, reason is as part of GUI design just drag and drop stuffs, use the autogenerated XRC in python code.

Comment: 1) You can grab what values are selected, however comboboxes only let you pick one. You should use `wx.ListBox` if you want multiple selection. 2) Just `Disable` the button after you click it. 3) `Enable` the button when the activity completes or when the `Stop` button is clicked. 4) See `wx.Listbox`

Comment: @MikeDriscoll    1) Yes, but i could able to print only object not exact values. Tried self.env = xrc.XRCCTRL(self.frame, 'list1') and self.env.GetValue() , i get AttributeError: 'StaticText' object has no attribute 'GetValue'

Comment: StaticText uses `GetLabel`

Comment: @MikeDriscoll GetLabel() gets the label, not the text selected.

Comment: I don't believe you can do what you want using a `StaticText` widget then. Also this should be moved to Stack's chat instead or you should start asking some new questions in a new post